# Increasing the Width of QLineF leads to change the start and end point of line(length)

Tags: qt

I am facing an issue with a `QLineF`. ( I am very new to QT)

After getting the start and End point for a `QlineF`, I am painting the line using `drawline()` function. 
Here we have an  option for user to edit the width of the drawn line using a `QSlider`.

Here I could able to change the width of the line but I could see some difference in the start and end point of a line. As there is an increase in the width of line, the length of the `Qline` is decreasing gradually.

Do anybody knows why this kind of behavior is happening? Please let me if you need any code snippet to be uploaded.

Edited: My paint code is here:

```
 void EyGsDistance::paint(QPainter * p, const QStyleOptionGraphicsItem * option, QWidget * widget)
 {    p->save();
QPen actPen;
if (isSelected() == true || isCurrent() == true)
    actPen = theActivePen;
else
    actPen = theInactivePen;
if(theMouseMoving == true)
{
    actPen.setStyle(Qt::DashLine);
}else
{
    actPen.setStyle(Qt::SolidLine);
}

p->setPen(actPen);
if (actPen.widthF() * p->transform().m11() < 1)
    p->setRenderHint(QPainter::Antialiasing, false);
else
    p->setRenderHint(QPainter::Antialiasing);
double length = sqrt(theVector.x() * theVector.x() + theVector.y() * theVector.y());
double coeff = (theArrowSize + 1.4 * actPen.widthF())/length;

double px = coeff * theVector.x();
double py = coeff * theVector.y();
if (sqrt(px * px +py * py) < length)
{
    QPointF point = QPointF(px, py);
    theCurrentLine->setP1(QPointF(0, 0) + QPointF(px, py));
    theCurrentLine->setP2(theVector);
    p->drawLine(*theCurrentLine);        
    this->updateDistanceText(QPointF(0, 0) + QPointF(px, py));

}

p->restore();       }
```

Comment: Post here your code please. I suppose that you use QPainter, so where do you paint and how?

Comment: Take a look at [this part of the docs](http://qt-project.org/doc/qt-5/coordsys.html).

Comment: I couldn't able to get solution from this doc. More help is appreciated.